# Django Celery Time Limit Exceeded?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I keep receiving this error...

```
[2012-06-14 11:54:50,072: ERROR/MainProcess] Hard time limit (300s) exceeded for movies.tasks.encode_media[14cad954-26e2-4511-94ec-b17b9a4149bb]

[2012-06-14 11:54:50,111: ERROR/MainProcess] Task movies.tasks.encode_media[bc173429-77ae-4c96-b987-75337f915ec5] raised exception: TimeLimitExceeded(300,)

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/srv/virtualenvs/filmlib/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 370, in _on_hard_timeout raise TimeLimitExceeded(hard_timeout)
TimeLimitExceeded: 300
```

even though I have `CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 86400` and `CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 86400` in my settings.py for the project. Does anyone know why would it still be defaulting to 300s?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Modify your celeryd (/etc/init.d/celeryd) settings. Sample below sets the time limit to 2 hours.

```
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=7200 -E --loglevel=DEBUG"
```