# Hard timeouts using celery with django

Tags: django, celery

Building on this question:

[Django Celery Time Limit Exceeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037105/django-celery-time-limit-exceeded)

I have some tasks that may run for sometime. However, most tasks should not take more then a few seconds. I don't want to set the global timeout to account for those long running tasks. Rather, I would like to have a global hard timelimit that is short, and manually adjust the tasks that I need to have a longer timeout.

When decorating the task with @task I did @task(timeout=None) and yet, that task still hit a timeout of 300 seconds. I called the task with task_function.delay(args).

Is there a way to call a task and customize it's timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/802) addresses the case when you can call a task with custom timeouts. It is implemented in [issue802 branch](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/issue802) but isn't in master yet. You can merge it with master and use the desired functionality.

With this patch, you can pass timeouts when calling tasks.

> tasks.add.apply_async(args=[1,2], soft_timeout=2, timeout=5)

Answer (score 2):

What version of celery are you running?  The [current stable docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-options) list `time_limit` as the correct argument for setting the timeout on a task and that the worker default will be used if no time limit is provided.  To set a long (e.g. 60 minute) timeout on a task you can use:

```
@task(time_limit=3600)
def mytask():
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can use apply_async to change the time limit when you call the task:

```
mytask.apply_async(time_limit=3600, args=args)
```

Comment: I tried both of the above, and in both cases the global settings are overriding. I'm using 2.5.5